# Add list of values as columns to existing dataframe using lapply in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataframe with a list of IDs and a function that can use each ID to:

- make an API call for data,
- summarize that data, and
- produce a list of results.

How can I merge the returned list of values for each ID, as columns, to the dataframe using lapply?

The example below replicates the process somewhat...I have a dataframe with IDs. The function returns a list of two values, for which I would like to add as columns to the dataframe myIDs.

```
myIDs <- as.data.frame(seq(1, 5))
names(myIDs) <- c("ID")

myfunc <- function (ID) {
  id.results <- list(add.one = ID + 1,
                     times.two = ID * 2
                    )
  return(id.results)
}

lapply(myIDs , function(x) myfunc(myIDs$ID))
```

Comment: Did you look at `dplyr::bind_rows`?

Comment: Did you try something like `df$new_column = lapply(df$id, your_function_to_make_api_call_and_summarize_and_produce_list_of_results)`?

Comment: No, I have not tried dplyr::bind_rows...I have mostly tried base R approaches. I will take a look.

Comment: I don't think `bind_rows` will be useful to you from your description, but if you show a little bit of sample data and results, maybe I'll be proven wrong. Maybe `bind_rows` on all the results and then `merge`...

Comment: @Gregor, yes - that works well if I return a single value...but I have list of multiple values that need to be added as columns.

Comment: Sounds like we need an example....

Comment: I should add that the returned list of values is unique for each ID.

Comment: Example has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not work depending on your data/function, but here's what I get from your question :

```
set.seed(111)
df <- data.frame(ID=1:100)

MyFunction <- function(x) return(list(id=x, res1=runif(1, max=x), res2=sample(letters,1)))

out <- apply(df, 1, MyFunction)
mylist <- do.call("rbind",out)
mydf <- as.data.frame(mylist)

attributes(mydf)
```

> ```
> > attributes(mydf)
> $names
> [1] "id"   "res1" "res2"
>
> $class
> [1] "data.frame"
>
> $row.names
>   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
>  [17]  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
>  [33]  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
>  [49]  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
>  [65]  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
>  [81]  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
>  [97]  97  98  99 100
> ```

Comment: It appears you are binding the rows returned, but not really adding them to the original df. This is sort of how I approached it, but using a for-loop over ID, and merging with the original df. The merging is needed because in reality, I have other data elements other than the IDs I wish to retain.